# disable parent page on layer show

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a hidden layer and when the user clicks a button the layer is set to show. How can I make the parent page become disabled/greyed out so the user cannot click anything on the parent page until the layer has been closed(set to hide)

similar to lightbox galleries

I call a function in the layer from the parent page from a button(edit) click

```
edit.onclick=function(){
        edit_box('show');           
    }
```

then on the layer I call the show function

```
function edit_box(showhide)
{
  if(showhide == "show")
    {
     document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="visible";
    }else if(showhide == "hide"){
      document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="hidden";        
    }   
 }
```

the css for the #popup is

```
#popupbox{ 
  padding:0; 
  margin: 0px auto; 
  background:white;
  border: solid #000000 1px; 
  z-index: 9000; 
  font-family: arial; 
  visibility: hidden; 
 }
```

and the html is

```
<div id="popupbox">
  <div class="close"><a href="javascript:edit_box('hide');" >close</a></div>
```

any pointers greatly appreciated as I do not know where to start on this one and can only find code relivent to pop up boxes elsewhere online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok sorted this out with

css on parent page

```
.black_overlay{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        z-index:1001;
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        opacity:.80;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    }
```

css on layer page

```
.white_content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 25%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 16px solid orange;
        background-color: white;
        z-index:1002;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

then the js on parent page within function calling popup layer

```
  document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'
```

html div on parent page

```
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

js on popup layer

```
 function edit_box(showhide){
    if(showhide == "show"){
    document.getElementById('popupbox').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="visible";
}else if(showhide == "hide"){
    document.getElementById('popupbox').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'
        document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="hidden";      
}
```

}

and the html on the layer

```
<div id="popupbox" class="white_content">
  <div class="close"><a href="javascript:edit_box('hide');" >close</a></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try with jQuery, jQuery（"#popupbox"）.hide();

Comment: no the popup box is on the layer. I want the parent page below the layer to be greyed out. I am currently using jquery for other things on the page so am looking for a jquery/jscript bit of code

Answer (score 0):

Change your style to

```
#popupbox{ 
  padding:0; 
  margin: 0px auto;
  position:fixed;
  top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom: 0;
  display:none;

  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  border: solid #000000 1px; 
  z-index: 9000; 
  font-family: arial; 
 }
```

and your function to

```
function edit_box(showhide)
{
  if(showhide == "show")
    {
     $('#popupbox').show();
    } else if (showhide == "hide") {
      $('#popupbox').hide();        
    }   
 }
```

---

if you want to support browsers that do not understand `rgba` colors then use a semi-transparent background .png image